# Order of Growth of a Sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, approximation

Let $n>k$ and $r$ be arbitrary positive integers. Define $q=k/n$. I want to show that

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{rk} \binom{rn}{i}q^i(1-q)^{rn-i}(rk-i)=\Theta(\sqrt{r})
$$

as $r\rightarrow \infty$. I've plotted stuff in Mathematica and am fairly certain the claim is true for all $n$ and $k$.

The obvious approach, of dividing the LHS by $\sqrt{r}$ and trying to show the limit is a positive constant, hasn't gotten me far. Stirling's approximation might be helpful as well. Not sure. One fact (admittedly only Mathematica-verified) which might be helpful is that

$$
rk\sum_{i=0}^{rk} \binom{rn}{i}q^i(1-q)^{rn-i}=\Theta(r).
$$
In other words, the "$-i$" in $(rk-i)$ is important.

Any ideas?

[In case you're curious, the hand-wavy motivation: the LHS is the loss from an algorithm which takes $rn$ samples and "accepts" the highest $rk$ of them. We're comparing our performance to a "first-best" algorithm which takes $rn$ samples and only accepts samples if they're in the top $q$-fraction of the distribution. This isn't important at all for the actual question, though.]

Answer (score 1):

You can write
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{rk} \binom{rn}{i} q^i (1-q)^{rn-i} (rk-i) = \\
rk \sum_{i=0}^{rk} \binom{rn}{i} q^i (1-q)^{rn-i} -
rn \sum_{i=1}^{rk} \binom{rn-1}{i-1} q^i (1-q)^{rn-i} = \\
rk \sum_{i=0}^{rk} \binom{rn}{i} q^i (1-q)^{rn-i} -
rn \sum_{i=0}^{rk-1} \binom{rn-1}{i} q^{i+1} (1-q)^{rn-i-1} = \\
rk \sum_{i=0}^{rk} \binom{rn}{i} q^i (1-q)^{rn-i} -
rk \sum_{i=0}^{rk-1} \binom{rn-1}{i} q^i (1-q)^{rn-1-i} = \\
rk (\Pr[\mathrm{Bin}(rn,k/n) \leq rk] - \Pr[\mathrm{Bin}(rn-1,k/n) \leq rk-1]) \approx \\
rk (\Pr[\mathrm{N}(rk,rk(1-k/n)) \leq rk] - \Pr[\mathrm{N}(rk-k/n,(rk-k/n)(1-k/n)) \leq rk-1]) \\ \approx
rk \left(\frac{1}{2} - \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1-k/n}{\sqrt{(rk-k/n)(1-k/n)}}\right) \right) \\ =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{rk\sqrt{1-k/n}}{\sqrt{rk-k/n}} \\ \approx
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sqrt{\frac{k(n-k)}{n}} \sqrt{r}.
$$
Here the first approximation is the normal approximation, the second approximation is that the normal density around 0 is roughly constant, and the third is neglecting $k/n$ when $k$ is large. If all the steps can be made rigorous, then you will have proved your result (with an explicit first order approximation).

Comment: Hm. I like the general thrust of the argument, and am embarrassed that I didn't see the binomial CDF in there. I'm most concerned about proving the asymptotic upper bound. Might there be a slightly slicker argument that notes that the fifth line is less than $rkP[\text{Bin}(rn-1,k/n)=rk]$? (Replace Bin(rn,k/n) in the first term with Bin(rn-1,k/n) to see why.) What're the asymptotic properties of this latter quantity?

Comment: It's perfectly possible that the argument can be simplified. If you manage to simplify it, you are welcome to post your own answer. Note, however, that the asymptotics of your suggested bound is roughly $rk/\sqrt{2\pi(k/n)(1-k/n)} = rn\sqrt{k/2\pi(n-k)}$ which grows linearly with $r$.